Vtiger Error Invalid reference specified for related_to
I use the code below to add comment to a Module in Vtiger:
problem is that when I want to add comment for Leads it works correctly; but when I set "related to" for my custom module show error below:
Invalid reference specified for related_to...
REFERENCE_INVALID
Please help me to solve it.
check my code and put your key and url to test it please
    <?php 
function callvtiger($url, $params, $type = "GET")
{
    $is_post = 0;
    if ($type == "POST") {
        $is_post   = 1;
        $post_data = $params;
    } else {
        $url = $url . "?" . http_build_query($params);
    }
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    if (!$ch) {
        die("Cannot allocate a new PHP-CURL handle");
    }
    if ($is_post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $is_post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    $return = null;
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        $return = false;
    } else {
        $return = json_decode($data, true);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $return;
}





$userName = "admin";
$userAccessKey = "**********";
$Url   = 'https://******/webservice.php';


$sessionData    = callvtiger($Url, array(
    "operation" => "getchallenge",
    "username" => $userName
));

echo "<pre>";print_r($sessionData);echo "</pre>"; echo "<br><br><br><br>";

$challengeToken = $sessionData['result']['token'];
$generatedKey   = md5($challengeToken . $userAccessKey);

$args = array(
    "operation" => "login",
    "username" => $userName,
    "accessKey" => $generatedKey
);

$dataDetails    = callvtiger($Url, $args , "POST");

echo "<pre>";print_r($dataDetails);echo "</pre>"; echo "<br><br><br><br>";
$sessionid = $dataDetails['result']['sessionName'];
$userId = $dataDetails['result']['userId'];
$id = explode("x",$userId );



$args = array(
    "operation"=>"create",
    "format"=>"json",
    "sessionName"=>$sessionid,
    "elementType"=>"ModComments",
    "element"=> json_encode( array(
        "commentcontent"=>"this is a test",
        "assigned_user_id"=>$userId,
        "related_to"=>"46x246",
    ) )
);


echo "<pre>";print_r($args);echo "</pre>"; echo "<br><br><br><br>";
$getCreateDetail = callvtiger($Url, $args, "POST");
echo "<pre>";print_r($getCreateDetail);echo "</pre>"; echo "<br><br><br><br>";



?>

